# Prevent Update Rollup for CRM 2011 running on Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011

we've been running to problems lately when our CRM 2011 automatically updates to the latest rollup (17 I think) coming from rollup 5. So what we've been doing now to resolve the problem is to uninstall the rollup since we're perfectly fine without the Rollup anyway. The problem is, after uninstalling the updates it just automatically updates itself again after some random time.

So the question is, is there a way to prevent CRM 2011 from automatically updating the Rollup? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: you are talking about the server rollup or the outlook client rollup?

Comment: By the looks of it outlook client rollup. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to manage the windows update settings of your client pc, however normally you have no issues using the latest outlook client, what matters is the server rollup.

Comment: Ahh windows update settings, I'll look into that. That's the problem though, the problem is in the outlook client and not the server rollup. Do you mind re-writing your comment as an answer so that I could accept it? :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Rollup for Dynamics CRM can be applied to the Server or to the Client Outlook.

In your case you are referring to the Client Outlook, if the rollup is automatically installed you need to change the settings inside Windows Update, because the Update Rollup are also released using that channel.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for this! And also, apparently my question is not valid or something as it got a downvote. So thank you for still offering your time to help a stranger :)

Comment: you got a downvote because this question i snot related to software development, next time you can ask on msdn forums or dynamics community forums

Comment: Really? I thought stackoverflow caters to any help regarding software. Haha, my bad. I'll go to the right forums next time.